# I can not Insert the @_Count=COUNT(*) sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
CountryList.Name,CountryList.Region_name,@_Count=COUNT(*)

FROM [p1].[dbo].[Ips] 
INNER JOIN [p1].[dbo].[CountryList] ON [CountryList].ID =[Ips].Country 
GROUP BY CountryList.Name,CountryList.Region_name,[Ips].Country
```

I can not Insert the @_Count=COUNT(*)
please help me
thanks

Comment: That would not have any real meaning, as you have many rows (Grouped by CountryList.Name,CountryList.Region_name,[Ips].Country) and you want to fill up one variable?

Comment: What are you going to do with this variable? Maybe you want to define a `CURSOR`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @Country_List TABLE
(
  Name char(3) ,
  Region_name nvarchar(50),
  _Count int
)
BEGIN TRANSACTION
 INSERT INTO @Country_List (Name, Region_name,_Count)
SELECT 
CountryList.Name,CountryList.Region_name,COUNT(*)

FROM [Ips] 
INNER JOIN [BlackSeo_CountryList] ON [CountryList].ID =[Ips].Country 
GROUP BY CountryList.Name,CountryList.Region_name,[Ips].Country

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM @Country_List


This OK
```